# Netflix Zuul and Ribbon Router

Tags: netflix-zuul

When need to authenticate to the backend service instance prior to the webservice call. Prior to using ribbon we have been using a Zuul pre filter to accomplish this. When switching to ribbon the pre filter now only has access to the service name and not the backend URI that will be invoked. How should this be handled ? Is it possible to register a pre-action with the ribbon router ?

thank you